# Child Fragment to Parent Fragment communication

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my child Fragment, I have a Recyclerview, and I haved an Appbar layout in my parent Fragment. When the Recyclerview's first item is visible, I need to update the appbar layout in my parent fragment

My interface

```
public interface OnListFirstItemVisibleListener {
    public void sendDataToFragmentOnFirstItemVisible(boolean data, int dy);
}
```

in Child Fragment class

```
public class MyChildFragment extends Fragment{
private OnListFirstItemVisibleListener mListFirstItemVisibleListener;
.............
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mListFirstItemVisibleListener=(OnListFirstItemVisibleListener) new ParentFragment();

        return view;
    }
 @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        if(mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==0&&mListFirstItemVisibleListener != null){
            mListFirstItemVisibleListener.sendDataToFragmentOnFirstItemVisible(true,dy);
        }else{
            mListFirstItemVisibleListener.sendDataToFragmentOnFirstItemVisible(false,dy);

        }

    }
```

In Parent Fragment class

I implemented the interface

```
public class MyParentFragment extends Fragment implements OnListFirstItemVisibleListener{

............

@Override
    public void sendDataToFragmentOnFirstItemVisible(boolean data, int dy) {
        if (dy < 0&&data==true)
            mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
    }

}
```

But I get Appbar layout as null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.setExpanded(boolean)' on a null object
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Make sure first that both of your Parent and Child Fragments are inflated in Activity.I think you Parent Fragment is not yet inflated in your activity and you are trying to call a method.

Comment: @prathamkesarkar How to make sure? I called it in onAttach, still its not working

Comment: onAttach doesn't help in making sure your views are inflated or not

Comment: Implement the listener in your activity instead. Access it in your child fragment. Then use the listener implemented in your activity to communicate things to parent fragment from child fragment. Access interface in onAttach() method in child fragment. When you have to pass a message interface.sendMessageToParent("Your_message_here"); You can access your parent fragment by associating with a tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the ChildFragmentManager. You Parent should look like this:

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mActionBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);
        mActionBar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.childHolder, new ChildFragment()).commit();
    }

    public void setActionBarHidden(boolean isHidden) {
        mActionBar.setVisibility(isHidden ? GONE : VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

And your child like this:

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {

    public ChildFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(mDataSet));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mParentFragment = (ParentFragment) getParentFragment();
        mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0 && mParentFragment != null) {
                    mParentFragment.setActionBarHidden(true);
                } else {
                    mParentFragment.setActionBarHidden(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ParentFragment parentFrag = ((ParentFragment)ChildFragment.this.getParentFragment());
parentFrag.YourParentFragmentMethod();
```

this is worked for me...

Comment: Surely this works, but the question is how good is this solution since its not expandable. For Ex. if this child fragment is being used by another Activity/Fragment, then this code needs to be surrounded by if/else .