# How to refresh parent fragment from a child fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a parent Fragment inside a ViewPager and the parent fragment contains also a ViewPager. The ViewPager contain the child fragments.
(Nested ViewPager)

Actually, I have an option to delete child fragment. When I delete the child fragment I have to refresh the parent fragment for refreshing the ViewPager.

I tried the code inside the parent fragment

```
public void restartFragment(){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
```

and I called this function from my child fragment

```
if ((TransactionList_Frg) getParentFragment() != null)
   ((TransactionList_Frg) getParentFragment()).restartFragment();
```

But this was not helped me.

Is there is any way to force refresh the parent fragment in the android studio? please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Child Fragment to Parent Fragment communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496442/child-fragment-to-parent-fragment-communication)

Comment: I tried that one but that won't help me.