# How to make the child fragment refreshed from it's Parent Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragmentmanager

Hello i have fragment and inside it viewpager with 2 tabs i need when i press button in the parent fragment refresh the child fragment inside viewpage 
i used this for refresh the same fragment and it's working fine

```
        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft1.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

i tried the same and instead of this i put the childfragment.newInstance() put still not refreshed so any suggestion ??

Comment: Refer this link [Child Fragment to Parent Fragment communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496442/child-fragment-to-parent-fragment-communication)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a interface in your child fragment.
      RefreshInterface
2. create a method in child fragment to assign a object to RefreshInterface.
      intialiseRefreshInterface(RefreshInterface refreshInterface)
3. call the interface method inside the refresh click.
4. implement the child fragment Interface in Parent fragment and override the method.
5. before commit() the child fragment from parent fragment
       1. create a object to child object
       2. call the intialiseRefreshInterface(RefreshInterface refreshInterface)
       3. commit() the child fragment.
6. your child fragment will refresh [ child fragment will be popBackStack() and re-create.

***Below example code will help you in achieve your requirement***

**Parent Fragment**

**parentFragment.java**

```
    public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements TwoFragment.RefreshInterface {

    TwoFragment child;
    Button launch;
    FrameLayout containerLayout;
    // child fragment interface object
    TwoFragment.RefreshInterface refreshInterface;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        launch = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_launch);
        containerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        // RefreshInterface. this is mandatory
        refreshInterface = this;
        launch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchChildFragment();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh_fragment() {
        // as we added the child fragment to backstack. we will remove the fragment from backstack and add again
        if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        launchChildFragment();
    }

    private void launchChildFragment(){
        // creating the object for child fragment
        child = new TwoFragment();
        // intialising the RefreshInterface object
        child.intialiseRefreshInterface(refreshInterface);
        // calling the child fragment
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, child).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

**fragment_parent.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.OneFragment">

    <Button
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_launch"
        android:text="Launch child fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_launch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**childFragment**

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

    Button refershBtn;
    RefreshInterface refreshInterface;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        refershBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_refersh);

        refershBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                refreshInterface.refresh_fragment();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void intialiseRefreshInterface(RefreshInterface refreshInterface){
        this.refreshInterface = refreshInterface;
    }

    public interface RefreshInterface {
        void refresh_fragment();
    }
}
```

**fragment_child.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.outthinking.myapplication.TwoFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/refersh_tv"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="REFRESH DATA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_refersh"
        android:text="refersh"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```